# Hints for exercise 7.3 from The elements of statistical learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I am stuck on problem 7.3 from the book 'The Elements of Statistical Learning'. This is the problem:
[image]

Here is my attempt to a solution for least-squares projections:

$$y_i-\hat f(x_i)=y_i-x_i^T(X_{-i}^TX_{-i})^{-1}X_{-i}^Ty,$$

where $X_{-i}$ is the matrix of training-example predictors with $i^{th}$ example (row) removed. Next I write
$$X_{-i}^TX_{-i}=X^TX-x_ix_i^T$$ and
$$X_{-i}^Ty_{-i}=X^Ty-x_iy_i.$$
Therefore,

$$y_i-\hat f(x_i)=y_i-x_i^T(X^TX-x_ix_i^T)^{-1}(X^Ty-x_iy_i).$$
I am not able to proceed further. It would be helpful if someone can give a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: please see a solution of ex. 7.3 here https://yuhangzhou88.github.io/ESL_Solution/ESL-Solution/7-Model-ASsessment-and-Selection/ex7-03/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints: You correctly note 
$$ X_{-i}^TX_{-i}=X^TX-\vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T$$($\vec{x_i}$ is a column vector),
and that you need to find $$\hat{\vec{\beta}}_{-i} = (X_{-i}^TX_{-i})^{-1}X_{-i}^T\vec{y}_{-i},$$ the estimated coefficients obtained by leaving out sample $i$. This will lead you to the new predicted value for sample $i$, $$ \hat f^{-i}(\vec{x}_i) = \vec{x}_i\hat{\vec{\beta}}_{-i}.$$ 
It will be useful to note that 
$$X_{-i}^T\vec{y}_{-i} = X^T\vec{y} - \vec{x}_iy_i,$$ and that you can use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to find the inverse of $(X^TX-\vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T)$. Also note that $$ \vec{x}_i^T(X^TX)^{-1}\vec{x}_i = S_{ii}.$$

You can then work out what you get for
$$\hat{\vec{\beta}}_{-i} = (X^TX-\vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T)^{-1}\left[X^Ty - \vec{x}_iy_i\right]$$ with a little algebra. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Let me try it out in some time. I will let you know then. it seems like I would be able to solve this using Sherman-Morrison formula. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked. I was able to solve it using Sherman-Morrison formula for $(X^TX-x_ix_i^T)^{-1}$